# Django Form Submit Update HTML

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

Instead of redirecting to a thank you page I would like to update the html of the current contact page after the response redirect.
For example, when the user hits the submit button they are brought back to the same page, however, the page now has a

tag thanking them.
I have no idea how to attempt this, or if it's possible.

**Views.py**

```
 if form.is_valid():
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/')
       message = 'Success!'
```

**HTML Page**

```
{% if message %}
   <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Another common method is to redirect with get params. Either `/contact/?success` which is detected in template, or literally the message to be displayed is also a pattern I see, but make sure it's escaped to prevent third party dom injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/):

```
if form.is_valid():
    messages.success(request, 'Success!')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/')
```

And then in the template:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

More advanced template can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages).